# Pra que serve o "= delete" na declaração de um construtor em C++?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, construtor, c++11

Me deparei com um construtor declarado da seguinte forma:

```
State(const State& em) = delete;
```

Alguém sabe pra que serve o `= delete` no final da assinatura do contrutor?

Comment: Nunca vi isso. Tem mais contexto?

Comment: Pior que não, só é pedido pra implementar o construtor de cópia e é dada essa assinatura.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Por padrão o C++ cria os construtores de cópia e de atribuição (*move*) para você com um código padrão. Se deseja que a classe não tenha esses construtores você precisa informar o compilador que ela deve ser "deletada", assim qualquer tentativa de chamar esses construtores dará erro.

Ao contrário do que parece você não está criando um construtor, está proibindo a sua criação.

Isso existe desde o C++11. Se tivessem pensado melhor provavelmente seria *opt-in* e não *opt-out* como teve que ficar por questões de compatibilidade. No começo ninguém achou que poderia existir uma classe sem esse construtor.

Ficou interessante proibir o construtor de cópia e deixar só o de atribuição funcionando que é muito mais eficiente, onde ele cabe.

Se algum lugar mandou implementar o construtor de cópia e mandou fazer assim, tem algo esquisito. Isso é o oposto de implementar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Saquei, então basicamente estou dizendo que o objeto State não vai ter construtor de cópia...

Comment: @JônatasTrabucoBelotti isso.

Comment: Boa resposta. É importante lembrar que, mesmo que o construtor seja marcado como deletado, ele ainda participa em resolução de sobrecarga (overload resolution), então a declaração ainda existe, mas caso esse construtor seja selecionado pela resolução, aí sim ocorre a proibição.

Comment: @MárioFeroldi é verdade.